# Error trying to edit character string inside struct string

Tags: arrays, c, string, struct

My program contains the next structure:

```
typedef struct user {
    char username[LENGTH_USERNAME];
} User
```

and I have an array inside my main function of struct user

```
User user_database[NUMBER_USERS];
```

The problem is that when I pass this database to a function to edit the username field of all the struct user in the array like this:

```
void initialize_empty_user_database(User database[])
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_USERS; ++i)
        database[i].username[0] = '\0';
}
```

when trying to compile, I get the next error:

```
 error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘User’ {aka ‘struct user’} from type ‘char *’
```

Here is the complete code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LENGTH_USERNAME 21
#define LENGTH_ACTIVITY_NAME    21
#define LENGTH_TASK_DESCR   51
#define NUMBER_USERS    50
#define NUMBER_ACTIVITIES   10
#define NUMBER_TASKS    10000

typedef struct user {
    char username[LENGTH_USERNAME];
    /* username cannot contain blank characters */
} User;


typedef struct activity {
    char name[LENGTH_ACTIVITY_NAME];      
    /* name cannot contain lowercase letters */
} Activity;

typedef struct task {
    int id;             
    char des[LENGTH_TASK_DESCR];                    /* description */
    User username[LENGTH_USERNAME];
    Activity activity[LENGTH_ACTIVITY_NAME];
    int etc;                                        /* Estimated Time of Completion */
    int start_time;     
} Task;

void initialize_empty_user_database(User database[])
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_USERS; ++i)
        database[i].username[0] = '\0';
}

void initialize_empty_activity_database(Activity database[])
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_ACTIVITIES; ++i)
        database[i].name[0] = '\0';
}

void initialize_empty_task_database(Task database[])
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_TASKS; ++i) {
        database[i].id = -1;                        /* id == -1 -> task not initialized */
    }
}

void read_task_descr(char target[])
{
    int i;
    char c;
    c = getchar();
    for(i = 0; i < (LENGTH_TASK_DESCR - 1) || c == '\n'; ++i){
        target[i] = c;
        c = getchar();
    }
    target[i] = '\0';
}

int available_tasks(Task database[])
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_TASKS; ++i) {
        if(database[i].id == -1)
            return NUMBER_TASKS - i;
    }
    return 0;
}

int duplicate_descr(Task database[], char descr[]) 
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_TASKS; ++i) {
        if (strcmp(database[i].des, descr) == 0)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int t_exceptions(Task task_database[], char task_descr[])
{
    if (available_tasks(task_database) == 0) {
        printf("too many tasks");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (duplicate_descr(task_database, task_descr) == 1) {
        printf("duplicate description"); 
        return 2;
    }
    return 0;
}

void new_task(Task database[], int etc, char descr[]) 
{
    static int i = 0;
    database[i].id = i + 1;                         /* id */
    strcpy(database[i].des, descr);                 /* descr */
    database[i].username[0] = '\0';                 /* username (not attributed) */
    strcpy(database[i].activity.name, "TO DO");     /* activity */
    database[i].etc = etc;                          /* estimated time for completion */
    database[i].start_time = 0;                     /* start time (not started) */
    ++i;
}


int main()
{
    /* Database declarations */
    User user_database[NUMBER_USERS];
    Activity activity_database[NUMBER_ACTIVITIES] = {{"TO DO"}, {"IN PROGRESS"}, {"DONE"}};
    Task task_database[NUMBER_TASKS];
    
    /* Variable and array definition */
    int time;
    int etc;                                        /* estimated time of completion */
    char task_descr[LENGTH_TASK_DESCR];
    char activity_name[LENGTH_ACTIVITY_NAME];
    char username[LENGTH_USERNAME];
    
    /* Auxiliary variables */
    char command;

    /* Database initilizations */
    initialize_empty_user_database(user_database);
    initialize_empty_activity_database(activity_database);
    initialize_empty_task_database(task_database);

    while(1) {
        command = getchar();
        switch(command) {
            case 'q':
                return 0;
            case 't':
                scanf("%d", &etc);
                getchar();  /* Consume space separating arguments */
                read_task_descr(task_descr);
                if(t_exceptions(task_database, task_descr) == 0)
                    new_task(task_database, etc, task_descr);       
                break;
            default:
                printf("Exception: Unknown command\n");
        }
        getchar(); /* Consume the newline character */
    }
    return -1;
}
```

can somebody explain to me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Errors in the original code are:

```
main.c: In function ‘new_task’:
main.c:103:31: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘User’ {aka ‘struct user’} from type ‘int’
  103 |     database[i].username[0] = '\0';                 /* username (not attributed) */
      |                               ^~~~
main.c:104:32: error: ‘(Activity *)&(database + (sizetype)((long unsigned int)i * 948))->activity’ is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?
  104 |     strcpy(database[i].activity.name, "TO DO");     /* activity */
      |                                ^
      |                                ->
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the line with the error?  They don't seem to match.

Comment: Please provide complete code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The code shown is incomplete and the error msg does not seem to match the code shown.

Comment: That is still not complete code. Show the **exact** code you are compiling and include the **exact** line number in the error msg. It should be complete to the extent that anyone can take the code, compile it and see your error.

Comment: The error is not on the line you have identified. It would really help if you gave the line number in the error msg. The error is this line: `database[i].username[0] = '\0';`. The type of `database` is `Task` and the type of `username` in that struct is a `User` array. You probably meant to make the `username` type to be `char username[LENGTH_UERNAME]` instead.

Comment: Thx, it was this, I needed to have .username->username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is on this line:

```
database[i].username[0] = '\0';
```

This is because `username` is declared to be a `User` array:

```
typedef struct task {
    int id;             
    char des[LENGTH_TASK_DESCR];                    /* description */
    User username[LENGTH_USERNAME];
    Activity activity[LENGTH_ACTIVITY_NAME];
    int etc;                                        /* Estimated Time of Completion */
    int start_time;     
} Task;
```

That looks like an error in the field declaration and should instead be:

```
char username[LENGTH_USERNAME];
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `user_database[i].username[0]` is of type `char`, so you need to assign a `char` and not a string to it.

```
user_database[i].username[0] = '\0';
```

Note the single quotes not double quotes `'\0'`.

Comment: Still getting the same error: main.c:103:31: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘User’ {aka ‘struct user’} from type ‘int’
  103 |     database[i].username[0] = '\0';

Comment: I copied all the code you provided and added a `main`, which contains only a single line in order to invoke your function: `initialize_empty_user_database(user_database);`  I don't get any compile errors or warnings and it executes fine.  You should copy the exact code so we can replicate it.